# OnChange with javascript/ajax result, also with a php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, foreach, onchange

I have this interesting setup that I hope someone can help me fix. I've searched and found some solutions but nothing that comes close to what I'm trying to achieve, so nothing really lead me in a direction that could get me to a solution for what I'm doing

I have a dropdown of litters. You select a litter, onchange happens, it gets the available pick spots from the database, then echos out the results with another foreach to another dropdown menu

The problem is, these dropdown menus are inside of a foreach loop (for each client available to the site user). So the first client works as expected, but because it has the same ID, the second client's dropdowns don't do anything since it's still on the same page

Hopefully someone has some insight on how to make this work :(

Here's the dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control mb-3" name="the_chosen_litter" id="litter" required>
<option disabled selected>First, Choose A Litter...</option>
<?php
foreach($labradoodle_two as $litter_waitlist_form){
?>
<option id="<?php echo $litter_waitlist_form['litter_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $litter_waitlist_form['litter_id']; ?>" style="<?php if($litter_waitlist_form['status']=='LITTER CLOSED'){ echo 'color:red;'; }else{ echo 'color:green;'; } ?>" >
<?php echo $litter_waitlist_form['litter_names']; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<select class="form-control mb-3" name="buyer_pick_gender" id="pick_list" required> <!-- uses jquery to fill in this field -->
<option disabled selected>Litter Selection Required...</option>
</select>
```

Here's the javascript/ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#litter").on("change", function() {
var litterID = document.getElementById("litter").value;
$.post('secure/litter_list_dropdown.php', { littersubmit: litterID }, function(result) {
$('#pick_list').html(result);
}
);
});
});
```

And for reference, here's my "litter_list_dropdown" code that pulls from the database and echos out the available "pick spots":

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../../database/dbh.class.php';

$litter_id = $_REQUEST['littersubmit'];

$femalespickedquery = $dbpdo->query("SELECT * FROM pick_assignment WHERE litter_id=? AND gender_id=?",$litter_id,"1")->fetchAll();
$malespickedquery = $dbpdo->query("SELECT * FROM pick_assignment WHERE litter_id=? AND gender_id=?",$litter_id,"2")->fetchAll();
?>

<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose A Pick</option>

<?php foreach ($femalespickedquery as $pick){
    $picktaken=$pick['user_id'];
    $pickcustom=$pick['custom_name']; 
    $pickposition=$pick['pick_id'];
    $suffix=ordinal($pickposition);
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $pickposition.' 1'; ?>" <?php if($picktaken!="0" OR $pickcustom==true){ echo "disabled"; } ?>>
        <?php echo "FEMALE - " .$pickposition.$suffix. " Pick"; if($picktaken!="0" OR $pickcustom==true){ echo " *RESERVED*"; }?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>

<?php 
foreach ($malespickedquery as $pick){
    $picktaken=$pick['user_id'];
    $pickcustom=$pick['custom_name']; 
    $pickposition=$pick['pick_id'];
    $suffix=ordinal($pickposition);
?>
    <option value=<?php echo $pickposition.' 2'; ?>" <?php if($picktaken!="0" OR $pickcustom==true){ echo "disabled"; } ?>>
        <?php echo "MALE - " .$pickposition.$suffix. " Pick"; if($picktaken!="0" OR $pickcustom==true){ echo " *RESERVED*"; }?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When you use same id attribute value for several elements on the page - you will face problems. You should avoid using id's at all unless you have a strong reason of using them. Did i get it right that you have several `select`'s with the same id?

Comment: do not use `id` attributes where there is possibility of duplicates like this. You can instead use the `event` which is triggered in the `change` event to identify the initial select menu and from that point use parent/sibling selectors to find other nodes of interest. If both select menus are within a common parent this task is very easy

Comment: Your code appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection as you are using request variables directly in the sql

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that but thanks anyways :) As for the injections, yes you are right, I use a class that prevents those things and I plan to use it correctly, I just haven't on this yet as it's behind tons of verification walls and I'm mainly just trying to get it to work first

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Edited to reflect prepared statement :)